# Google Map View, use "My places" map on android app

Tags: android, google-maps, view

I would like to create an android app, which using Google Map View and display my own map.
I started my app from this link

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

But in step two I would like to add these POI points to my app:

http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF&msa=0&msid=203009957035125689590.0004abe0f3ee68f732c31

(This is the map of 'Budapest university of technology and economics' and I would like to create an app that everyone can download and navigate themselves to the right building)

Is it possible? If it is, how can I do that?
Thanks!
Greg.